# How to increase the memory for OpenEJB standalone container?

Tags: memory, configuration, openejb

Usually we just find the -Xm switch of the JVM and increase that, but it seems that OpenEJB 4.0.0 is using a Javaagent to initiate the JVM.

How can we increase the heap limit of RAM in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way.  The `-javaagent:` flag has no effect on how memory is set.

Side note, you only need the `-javaagent` option if either one of these is true:

- you are using OpenJPA as your JPA provider
- you are using CMP2 `EntityBean`s.